# Create a Join Query using CiriteriaBuilder JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need the following query to be get created using CriteriaBuilder

```
  SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName
  FROM Orders
  INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

CriteriaBuilder Code:

```
  CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Customers> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Customers.class);
    Root<Customers> root = criteriaQuery.from(Customers.class);
    Join<Customers, Orders> emailTemplateMaster = root.join(Customers_.customerId, JoinType.INNER);
```

**Need not know the remaining code How to related the tables**

I have used the Join functionality. But my question how to get the List of customers with orders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
     CriteriaQuery<String> q = cb.createQuery(String.class);
     Root<Order> order = q.from(Order.class);
     q.select(order.get("shippingAddress").<String>get("state"));

     CriteriaQuery<Product> q2 = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
     q2.select(q2.from(Order.class)
                 .join("items")
                 .<Item,Product>join("product"));
```

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html